# How to allow logged in user to view their own civicrm contact dashboard in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard, 5.0

I want to allow logged in user to edit own contact details(own) from contact dashboard and edit custom fields(own)
[image]

WordPress Version 4.9.8
CiviCRM Version 5.5.1

Comment: Did you try giving permission for edit own contact details?

Comment: @PradeepNayak, should I check it out in the Wordpress Roles?

Comment: Hi @PradeepNayak, I don't see that permissions in wordpress Roles permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving permission to user 'edit own contact' will be able to update his own details.  You can check permission by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Users and Permissions >> Permissions (Access Control) and then click on Wordpress access control

Comment: Hi
After Saving permissions, I get Notice: Undefined index: administrator in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/ACL/Form/WordPress/Permissions.php on line 154
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/ACL/Form/WordPress/Permissions.php:154) in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Base.php on line 926

Answer (score 0):

To View your own contact dashboard

1) Add WordPress Plugin **Members**

2) Go to individual Role's permissions page and then tick Access Civicrm.

3) Visit **Wordpress Access Control** under Users and Permissions as mentioned in answer given above and select following permissions.
- View my contacts
- Edit my contacts
- Access my contact dashboard