# Contact Dashboard in Wordpress

Tags: dashboard, user-dashboard

Does anyone know if this information on Configuring Front-end Contact Dashboard in Joomla Sites is possible in Wordpress? If so, where can I find the corresponding information?

CiviCRM includes the ability to expose a Contact Dashboard which gives logged in front-end users the ability to view their subscribed groups, membership(s), contribution(s) and registered events. This section covers adding a link to this page to your front-end site menus.

Answer (score 1):

The settings for what shows on Contact Dashboard are at https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpreferences%2Fdisplay&reset=1

and here is link to the Dashboard itself

https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/user&reset=1

Comment: there may be some helpful info here too https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26527/how-to-allow-logged-in-user-to-view-their-own-civicrm-contact-dashboard-in-wordp